# css timeline alternative to absolute values

Tags: html, css, timeline

I am trying to make a timeline where dots are connected. Thing 1 dots can be connected to "dots" later on in the timeline on thing 2, 3 rows (basically a report and then a number of actions tied to it). I was wondering if there is a better way to do it than a lot of **position: absolute**  ?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 290px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.circle {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background-color: #dd35e7;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #352;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.circle--first {
  left: 70px;
  top: 50px;
}

.circle--second {
  left: 320px;
  top: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

.circle--third {
  left: 120px;
  top: 50px;
  z-index: 30;
}

.circle--fourth {
  left: 370px;
  top: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

.line {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 100;
}

.line--first {
  left: 80px;
  top: 54px;
  width: 245px;
  height: 3px;
  background-size: 10px 2px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
.line--second {
  left: 325px;
  top: 56px;
  width: 2px;
  height: 145px;
  background-size: 2px 10px;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
}

.line--third {
  left: 131px;
  top: 54px;
  width: 247px;
  height: 3px;
  background-size: 10px 2px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

.line--fourth {
  left: 375px;
  top: 56px;
  width: 3px;
  height: 45px;
  background-size: 2px 10px;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
}

.axes {
  position: relative;
}
.axis {
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-left-style: solid;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  border-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.8);
  height: 290px;
}

.labels {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.date {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  top: 245px;
  width: 50px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle circle--first">
  </div>
  <div class="circle circle--second"></div>
  <div class="circle circle--third"></div>
  <div class="circle circle--fourth"></div>
  <div class="line line--first"></div>
  <div class="line line--second"></div>
  <div class="line line--third"></div>
  <div class="line line--fourth"></div>
  <div class="axes">
    <div class="axis" style="left: 100px;"></div>
    <div class="axis" style="left:150px;"></div>
    <div class="axis" style="left:200px;"></div>
    <div class="axis" style="left:250px;"></div>
    <div class="axis" style="left:300px;"></div>
    <div class="axis" style="left:350px;"></div>
    <div class="axis" style="left:400px;"></div>
    <div class="axis" style="left:450px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="labels">
    <span style="left: 10px; top: 45px; position: absolute;">Thing 1</span>
    
    <span style="left: 10px; top: 95px; position: absolute;">Thing 2</span>
    
    <span style="left: 10px; top: 145px; position: absolute;">Thing 3</span>
    
    <span style="left: 10px; top: 195px; position: absolute;">Thing 4</span>
    <span class="date" style="left: 61px;">Aug 2021</span>

    <span class="date" style="left: 111px;">Sep 2021</span>

    <span class="date" style="left: 161px;">Oct 2021</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Position absolute for the action lines seems OK to me. Is it a problem in your use-case? What is an issue is the use of fixed units (px) which makes the thing non-responsive. Is that a problem in your use case?

Comment: Are other things tied to Thing 2 or Thing 3 etc in the same way as they are to Thing 1 or is it always descending from Thing 1?

Comment: they might go to different levels basically. But if feels like a lot of work creating all the absolute values. Especially if the timeline grows into seconds years etc but maybe it is really the best option

Answer (score 1):

One way of not having to calculate all the absolute values is to get CSS to do it for you by putting everything in a grid.

This snippet sets up a grid with the first column with 'things' captions and the last row as the months.

It uses before and after elements to draw the lines between activities (circles) and the one they are joined to.

This is quite a simple layout, without knowing the full structure of how activities may be joined together it's hard to say whether this is enough. It's enough to enable us to draw the timeline given in the question so hopefully will lead to some ideas for the situation where activities can be joined to more than one other activity. This would be possible to do keeping the method of drwawing the lines (background images which are linear gradients) because you can have as many as you like in one background-image declaration.

```css
.timeline,
.timeline *,
.timeline *::before,
.timeline *::after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.timeline {
  --timelineW: 100vw;
  --thingH: 10vmin;
  --numThings: 4;
  /* the things are in rows 1 to numTasks */
  --Thing1: 1;
  --Thing2: 2;
  --Thing3: 3;
  --Thing4: 4;
  --numMonths: 4;
  /* the months are in columns 2 to (numMonths + 1) */
  --Sept: 2;
  --Oct: 3;
  --Nov: 4;
  --Dec: 5;
  width: var(--timelineW);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(calc(var(--numMonths) + 1), 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
  grid-auto-rows: var(--thingH);
  grid-gap: 0;
}

.thing {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: var(--n);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.month {
  grid-row: calc(var(--numThings) + 1);
  grid-column: var(--n);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.activity {
  background-image: radial-gradient(var(--bg) 0 50%, transparent 50% 100%);
  background-size: 5vmin 5vmin;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  grid-column: var(--month);
  grid-row: var(--thing);
  height: var(--thingH);
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.activity::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  width: calc((var(--joinMonth) - var(--month)) * (var(--timelineW) / (var(--numMonths) + 1)));
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(transparent 0 calc(50% - 1px), blue calc(50% - 1px) calc(50% + 1px), transparent calc(50% + 1px) 100%);
  z-index: -1;
}

.activity::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: calc((var(--joinMonth) - var(--month)) * (var(--timelineW) / (var(--numMonths) + 1)));
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc((var(--joinThing) - var(--thing)) * var(--thingH));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 0 calc(50% - 1px), blue calc(50% - 1px) calc(50% + 1px), transparent calc(50% + 1px) 100%);
  z-index: -1;
}

.red {
  --bg: red;
}

.blue {
  --bg: blue;
}

.green {
  --bg: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline">
  <div class="thing" style="--n: 1;">Thing1</div>
  <div class="thing" style="--n: 2;">Thing2</div>
  <div class="thing" style="--n: 3;">Thing3</div>
  <div class="thing" style="--n: 4;">Thing4</div>

  <div class="month" style="--n: var(--Sept);">Sept</div>
  <div class="month" style="--n: var(--Oct);">Oct</div>
  <div class="month" style="--n: var(--Nov);">Nov</div>
  <div class="month" style="--n: var(--Dec);">Dec</div>
  <div class="activity blue" style="--month: var(--Nov); --thing: var(--Thing3)"></div>
  <div class="activity green" style="--month: var(--Dec); --thing: var(--Thing4)"></div>
  <div class="activity red" style="--month: var(--Sept); --thing: var(--Thing1); --joinThing: var(--Thing4); --joinMonth: var(--Dec);"></div>
  <div class="activity red" style="--month: var(--Oct); --thing: var(--Thing1); --joinThing: var(--Thing3); --joinMonth: var(--Nov);"></div>
```